# How can I perform Incremental load in informatica?

Tags: informatica

i want to load data into target table. the load will be delta(Incremental). I want load initial load and later i will schedule daily jobs. how can i do this using parameter file.

Comment: Do you have a timestamp column based on which you can select Delta data?

Comment: Yes I have but I need to automate for both initial and daily load in same file or variable

Answer (score 0):

Create a **mapping variable** say `$LOAD_DATE`. In the SQ overide query put a condition `UPDT_TS > $$LOAD_DATE`.

Also in an expression transformation, use `SETVARIABLE` function to set the variable to `SESSIONSTARTTIME`.

Now for the initial load, set `$$LOAD_DATE=01/01/1900` in the parameter file.

For delta loads simply remove the parameter from the parameter file. It will take the value saved in repository, which is the last load date.

Comment: Any other way I heard using shell scripting

Comment: Sure you can implement the same logic in shell script as well

Comment: Can you give sample code or link where can I get sample code. And how how can I configure the code so it will run in informatica.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any readily available sample code. But anyway, the code would be specific to your project. Basically, what you need to do is, store the load date and time in a file and read the last load date and time and update the parameter file.